# Remove Minimize button for QMessageBox on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi

I am running my Qt5 application on a Raspberry Pi 3 using the xcb platform in full screen mode.
My problem is it's possible to minimize the whole application from all the QMessageBox because the popup messages have a minimize button...

The function setWindowFlags() is ignored so it's not possible to remove the minimize button.

`msgBox->setWindowFlags( Qt::Dialog );
...
msgBox->setWindowFlags( Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint );`

[QMessageBox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPKvT.png)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Instead of `setWindowFlags`, try `msgBox->reparent( NULL, Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint );`

Comment: is your msgBox modal? Maybe you can try calling msgBox->show() instead of exec(). Kind of hard to answer without a minimal working example that reproduces the error!

Comment: `msgBox->reparent(...)` doesn't exist. I guess `msgBox->setParent(NULL, Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);` is the same? 
However it doesn't remove the Minimize button.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that each call to `setWindowFlags` overrides previous, you'd need to use or-ed flags:

```
msgBox->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

On the other hand, following works for me in a similar scenario in Windows, where I need `QDialog` to have the close button only:

```
msgBox->setWindowFlags(msgBox->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
```

Comment: I know it overrides previous value. Both values should works but it doesn't. It seems to be ignored.

Comment: Maybe Qt is not 100% compatible with your windows manager? Have you tested in any other platform?